# Add to cart button freezes and nothing is put in basket

Tags: magento2, addtocart

We currently run a Magento 2 Store with the Porto theme from Smartwave.

We use the TIG PostNL extension for shipping.
After the latest update of this extension the add to cart button doesn't work anymore.
The nice people at TIG checked it and said nothing is disturbing the process.

In the log files I found:

> [06-Jul-2018 05:30:15 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a
>   member function getParentItem() on null in
>   /home/fotoloom/public_html/app/code/Smartwave/Dailydeals/Observer/DealProductDiscountPrice.php:27
>   Stack trace: 0
>   /home/fotoloom/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(72):
>   Smartwave\Dailydeals\Observer\DealProductDiscountPrice->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
>   1
>   /home/fotoloom/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(60):
>   Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Smartwave\Dailydeals\Observer\DealProductDiscountPrice),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer)) 2
>   /home/fotoloom/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66):
>   Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array,
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer)) 3
>   /home/fotoloom/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95):
>   Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('checkout_cart_p...', Array)
>   4 /home/fotoloom/public_html/v in
>   /home/fotoloom/public_html/app/code/Smartwave/Dailydeals/Observer/DealProductDiscountPrice.php
>   on line 27**

It appears to me this could cause the error. However Smartwave says it also happens if the template is disabled.

I am looking for a solution and can't find it.

Could you tell me where to look to solve this issue? Clients are walking away and already a weak trying to find a solution. Even the hoster says nothing on their side and Redis is configurated well.

I am desperate right now.

Answer (score 0):

Check line number 27 in the class file /home/fotoloom/public_html/app/code/Smartwave/Dailydeals/Observer/DealProductDiscountPrice.php

The error message itself shows the path to debug and solve. getParentItem() is getting called on any null object.

your problem seems very specific with a particular situation, so it won't be possible to give you exact solution for this.

Comment: We solved it by just removing the extension.
The extension is obsolete. We don't use.
It also appeared to me that after we removed it, the page load time went significant down.

Answer (score 0):

We solved it by just removing the extension. The extension is obsolete. We don't use. It also appeared to me that after we removed it, the page load time went significant down.

So, this ticket can be closed. How do I do that?

Comment: use this guide: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37752/how-do-i-close-my-own-question/37753